# Relationship upload

Tags: relationships, upload

I have a list of students and their corresponding emergency contacts to upload into SF. I would like to have the emergency contact connected to the student in some way (i.e. have SF reflect that Parent A is the mother of Student A). Is there a way to do a relationship upload in SF where the Parents/emergency contacts will be connected to the students contact record)

(All students and contacts are already in SF)

Comment: Are you using the Nonprofit Success Pack?  If not, you'll have to create your own object to link the contacts.  See this [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_modeling/object_relationships) for the basics of how database records can be related to one another.

Comment: Yes! I am using the Nonprofit Success Pack and we already have the relationships object. I just am not sure how I can connect the student will the parent/emergency contact in an upload (I am currently using Zaapit or the data loader to upload data)

Comment: You can [import Relationship records](https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/NPSP-Advanced-Mapping-Recipes#ariaid-title8) using the NPSP Data Import process.  FYI, the best resource for NPSP support is the [Power of Us Hub](https://powerofus.force.com/publogin), where there are many discussion groups and participants.

Answer (score -2):

If all the students and contacts are already in salesforce, export them to excel along with their IDs, and in the Related id field in Students, paste the IDs of contacts in ContactId field in student and it will reflect in SF.